# Listing all values for a key with Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have in front of me a JSON file :

```
{
  "category": "burglary",
  "location_type": "Force",
  "month": "2014-03"
}, {
  "category": "violence",
  "location_type": "Force",
  "month": "2014-03"
}
```

Now, I am trying to get me head around underscore.js, with a certain satisfaction so far. 
What I would like to do is to create a new array (let's call it `values`) and fill it with a list of the different values the `category` key can have.

This way, I will be able to call `values[1]` later to refer to `"burglary"` in this example.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) will work for you

```
data = [{
  "category": "burglary",
  "location_type": "Force",
  "month": "2014-03"
}, {
  "category": "violence",
  "location_type": "Force",
  "month": "2014-03"
}]


console.log(_.pluck(data,'category'))
```

output

```
[ 'burglary', 'violence' ]
```

Comment: Great, many thanks - and sorry for the somehow stupid/basic question!

Comment: before using a library, just go through the docs, that will tell why should you use it. @basbabybel

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var test = [{
  "category": "burglary",
  "location_type": "Force",
  "month": "2014-03"
}, {
  "category": "violence",
  "location_type": "Force",
  "month": "2014-03"
}];

var testArray = new Array();

test.forEach(function(data) {

    testArray.push(data.category);

});

console.log(testArray[0]);
console.log(testArray[1]);
```

Don't forget that indexes start at 0 in JavaScript.

Comment: I accepted @Mritunjay's answer, I was looking for an Underscore solution. Thanks to you anyway!